# wikitude does not show icon

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I have a problem with Wikitude on Android, the icons related at the POI are not shown, I have the market but without the icon. I set the icon in this way:

```
poi1.setIconresource("com.mitcom.wigo:drawable/icon_48x48");
```

where icon_48x48 is the resource.
The strange thing is that I was able to show the icon in dev mode, when I put the app on the market I faced this problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

have you tried it with `setIconResorce(getResources().getResourceName(R.drawable.icon_48x48));`

I think it  will solve your problem.